# How can I use a version of Java that isn’t supported in Azure App Service

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to create a Java application on Microsoft Azure in a web app. The web app service has provides some Tomcat and Jetty versions with default configuration. i want to host an application that doesn't use these default versions and configuration. is this doable or should I opt for VM instead?

Comment: which Java version and what kind of configurations would you like to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is doable. But in this case you will need to create a web app and then manually copy and edit configuration files.

This method is good for:

- Java applications that require a version of Tomcat or Jetty that isn't directly supported by App Service or provided in the gallery. (Your case)
- Java application that takes HTTP requests and does not deploy as a WAR into a pre-existing web container.
- Configure the web container from scratch.
- Use a version of Java that isn’t supported in App Service and want to upload it yourself.

For cases like these, you can create an app using the portal, and then provide the appropriate runtime files manually.

Here is the tutorial for implementing this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/

Answer (score 1):

You can also deploy a Docker container with your specific Tomcat version. Please see [Web Apps for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image).

Comment: Hello Jason, Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You may want to edit in an overview/synopsis of the instructions in the link, in case the link is not valid at some point in the future.